# Changes to placemark addressDictionary in xcode 7 Beta 6

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have upgraded to xcode 7 beta 6 as iOS 9 will be on us soon. I was very pleased that my code converted without too much hassle except for one exception.

It seems that the `placemark.addressDictionary` has been changed to `[NSObject: AnyObject]`?

This was my code in xCode 6 for a map search

```
for item in response.mapItems as! [MKMapItem] {
     var placeMarkAddress = item.placemark.addressDictionary
     let street:String = placeMarkAddress["Street"] != nil ? placeMarkAddress["Street"] as! String : ""
}
```

This no longer works as `placeMarkAddress` is now `[NSObject: AnyObject]`?

How do I get the value (`AnyObject`) out by referencing the `NSObject` by name?

I've tried this in xcode7

```
 for item in response!.mapItems {
     var placeMarkAddress = item.placemark.addressDictionary
     for placeMarkAddress in placeMarkAddresses!{
          print(placeMarkAddress)
     }
 }
```

The output I get is this.

```
 (FormattedAddressLines, [440 Castro St, San Francisco, CA  94114-2020, United States])
 (Street, 440 Castro St)
 (SubAdministrativeArea, San Francisco)
 (Thoroughfare, Castro St)
 (ZIP, 94114)
 (Name, 440 Castro)
 (City, San Francisco)
 (PostCodeExtension, 2020)
 (Country, United States)
 (State, CA)
 (SubLocality, Castro)
 (SubThoroughfare, 440)
 (CountryCode, US)
```

This maybe obvious to some of you but I'm still a bit of a newbie to iOS development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `placeMarkAddress` is `[NSObject: AnyObject]?`, you must unwrap it before using it.  The optional chaining `?` is appropriate here; it will unwrap the dictionary if it isn't `nil` or it will just safely return `nil` if the dictionary is `nil`.

Instead of checking explicitly for `nil` and using the `? :` operator to substitute `""`, there is a special operator to do that called the *nil coalescing operator* `??` which is used like this:

```
let street = placeMarkAddress?["Street"] as? String ?? ""
```

---

Writing the statement in this way protects you in 4 ways:

1. If `placeMarkAddress` is `nil`, the *optional chain* `placemarkAddress?["Street"]` will return `nil`, the *optional cast* `as? String` will turn that `nil` into a `String?` with a `nil` value, and `??` will replace that with empty string `""`.
2. If  `"Street"` is not a valid key in the dictionary, `placeMarkAddress?["Street"]` will return `nil` and that will be converted to `""` as stated in point 1.
3. If the value in the dictionary corresponding to key `"Street"` has a type other than `String`, then the *conditional cast* will return a `String?` with a value of `nil` which `??` will convert to `""`.
4. Finally, using the *nil coalescing operator* `??` safely unwraps the value from the dictionary if it exists and is a `String`, otherwise it substitutes the supplied default value (empty `String` `""`).

Comment: Thanks for this. I understand the concept of unwrapping but it feels somewhat abstract at times and catches me out now and then. I thought I had tried this but obviously I hadn't.

Comment: There is a lot of wisdom in the design of Swift, but handling optionals does take practice.

Comment: I have this peace of code:
if let address=placeMark.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"][0]? as? String 
and I get the same error.